# Android app can not use HttpClient After Android proguard

Tags: android, https, httpclient, proguard

When my android app proguard, My app try to connect to https server, the connection be refused.I don't know why.So i package an apk without proguard and do the same test, the app run normally and connected the https server successfully. This is my proguard config:

```
-optimizationpasses 5`    `

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames `    `

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses`    `

-dontpreverifyenter`    `

-verbose`    `

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*`    `

-ignorewarnings`    `

-libraryjars libs/android-support-v4.jar`    `

-libraryjars libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar`    `

-libraryjars libs/libqblueota v0.96.jar`    `

-libraryjars libs/zxing.jar`    `

-keep class com.zxing.** {*; }`    `

-keep class android.support.** {*;}`    `

-keep class org.apache.** {*;}`    `

-keep class com.nostra13.universalimageloader.** {*;}`    `

-keep class com.google.zxing.** {*;}`    `

-keep class android.** {*; }`    `

-keep class com.sengled.cloud.service.** {*;}`    `

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity`    `

-keep public class * extends android.app.Application`    `
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service`    `

-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver`    `

-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper

-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference

-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {native <methods>;}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Comment: Take the exception stack, translate the obfuscated class/method names against the mapping generated by proguard and see what exactly is causing the problem.

Comment: It is likely that the exception trace from `adb logcat` will also show the name of the missing class. PS after you solve your problem, please post the answer.

Comment: yeah, this is the exception statck:W/System.err﹕ a.a.a.c.m: Connection to https://10.101.101.51:8443 refused
W/System.err﹕ at a.a.a.f.c.h.a(Unknown Source)

Comment: So, It seems i have nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: may I ask where you got hold of libqblueota from?